# Getting the total size of a directory as a number with du

Tags: string, bash, cut

Using the command `du`, I would like to get the total size of a directory

Output of command `du myfolder`:

```
5454 kkkkk
666  aaaaa
3456788 total
```

I'm able to extract the last line, but not to remmove the string `total`:

```
du -c myfolder | grep total | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Results in:

```
3456788 total
```

Desired result

```
3456788
```

I would like to have all the command in one line.

Comment: What if there's a *tab* between the fields (which is most likely the case here)? Note that the default field delimiter for `cut` *is* the tab character.

Comment: `du -s myfolder | cut -f1` or to put in variable `value`, without using `cut` but some bashism: `read value _ < <(du -s myfolder)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because it's tab delimited (which is the default delimiter of cut):

```
~$ du -c foo | grep total | cut -f1
4
~$ du -c foo | grep total | cut -d'   ' -f1
4
```

to insert a tab, use Ctrl+v, then TAB

Alternatively, you could use awk to print the first field of the line ending with `total`:

```
~$ du -c foo | awk '/total$/{print $1}'
4
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, you probably want to use `tail -n1` instead of `grep total` ... Consider what happens if you have a directory named `local`? :-)

Now, let's look at the output of `du` with `hexdump`:

```
$ du -c tmp | tail -n1 | hexdump -C
00000000  31 34 30 33 34 34 4b 09  74 6f 74 61 6c 0a        |140344K.total.|
```

That''s the character `0x09` after the `K`, `man ascii` tells us:

```
   011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I
```

It's a tab, not a space :-)

The tab character is already the default delimiter (this is specified in the POSIX spec, so you can safely rely on it), so you don't need `-d` at all.

So, putting that together, we end up with:

```
$ du -c tmp | tail -n1 | cut -f1
140344K
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `-s` to summarize it? This way you don't have to `grep "total"`, etc.

```
$ du .
24  ./aa/bb
...
       # many lines
...
2332    .
$ du -hs .
2.3M    .
```

Then, to get just the value, pipe to `awk`. This way you don't have to worry about the delimiter being a space or a tab:

```
du -s myfolder | awk '{print $1}'
```

---

From `man du`:

```
   -h, --human-readable
          print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

   -s, --summarize
          display only a total for each argument
```

Comment: This still means you end up with `<size><tab><dirname>` & a non-working `cut`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker uhms, I had missed that part from the question. Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using awk for this:

```
value=$(du -c myfolder | awk '/total/{print $1}')
```

This simply extracts the first field of the line that matches the pattern "total".

If it is always the last line that you're interested in, an alternative would be to use this:

```
value=$(du -c myfolder | awk 'END{print $1}')
```

The values of the fields in the last line are accessible in the `END` block, so you can get the first field of the last line this way.